# Как через js записать стиль css?

Tags: javascript, css

Я пробовал через `document.write()` записать в тег `<style></style>` стиль css, но не вышло.
Как еще можно попробовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сочувствуем.

```js
function addStyle() {
  var s = document.createElement("style");
  s.textContent = ".two{background:lightgreen;}";
  document.body.appendChild(s);
}
```

```css
.one {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one two"></div>
<br/>
<button onclick="addStyle()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Можно просто через style.cssText = “background: lightgreen “

Answer (score 1):

```js
let js = document.getElementById('js-styles');

js.append( ` .test {color: orange; font-size: 25px;}` ); // Добавление класса
// С такими кавычками можно свободнее писать стили из серии content: "..."; 

js.textContent = js.textContent.replace(/\.bubu\s*{.*?}/, ""); // Удаление класса
```

```html
<style id="js-styles"> .bubu { color: red; } .dudu { color: green; }</style>

<p class="bubu">Тест - bubu</p>
<p class="dudu">Тест - dudu</p>
<p class="test">Тест - test</p>
```

Значение регулярки можно узнать здесь → https://regex101.com/r/LuMoWN/1